# Laravel conditional View for https

Tags: php, laravel, https, laravel-routing, symfony-http-foundation

I want to return a view from my controller function with `https` or `http` depending on a variable. I don't want to `redirect` it to `https` or `http` and I only want to use `View::make()` or `Response::view()` function. Is it possible?

Example:

```
public function getSiteContent($https = false)
{
  if($https===true){
    //return to secure https url
    return View::make('sites.content');
  }
  else{
    //return to http url
    return View::make('sites.content');
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to change the protocol the user is using then you would **have** to redirect, there is no alternative.

Comment: @Jono20201, My concept and thinking is if we are going to a new url than we should have control over protocol. If we can change headers by `Response::view()` than why we can't change the protocol?

Comment: @interstellarDust because response depends on request. In order to return https response you need to make https request.

Answer (score -2):

First I understood question wrong. Returning view just returns the content on the page and View does not have anything to do with the protocol.

If protocol change is needed then only way is to redirect to https or http whatever you prefer.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. :(

Comment: this is not what the OP asking for